# Can't change xtick font size in Matlab subplot

Tags: matlab

I'd like to change the font size of the x & y tick labels, but have only been able to change the size of the y tick labels.

Below is the code that changes only the font size of the y tick labels:

```
figure(1);
for z=1:length(percentsolar)
    for i=1:h
        percentimprovement4(:,i) = percentimprovement2(1,:,i,z,1);
    end
    ax(z) = subplot(3,2,z);
    boxplot(percentimprovement4);
    set(ax(z), 'fontsize', 6);
    ylabel('% improvement', 'fontsize',8,'fontweight', 'bold');
    xlabel('Hour of the day', 'fontsize', 8,'fontweight', 'bold');
    title(['PF improvement for ', num2str(percentsolar(z)),'% solar penetration'], 'fontsize', 10 ,'fontweight', 'bold');
    clear percentimprovement4
end
linkaxes(ax);
saveas(gcf,'Boxplotshourly.jpg');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/answers/2461-boxplot-xtick-label-size):

> boxplot() uses the default axes labeling for the Y axes, but for the X
>   axes, it uses    text() to put the labels in place and it does not
>   grab the axes FontSize when it does so.

Thus, in addition to `set(ax(z), 'fontsize', 6);` you should also use `set(findobj(ax(z),'Type','text'),'FontSize',  6);`. For example,

```
figure(1);


percentsolar = zeros(1,6);

 z = 6;
 ax = zeros(0, length(percentsolar));

 for z = 1:length(percentsolar)
    ax(z) = subplot(3,2, z);

    x1 = normrnd(5,1,100,1);
    x2 = normrnd(6,1,100,1);


    boxplot([x1, x2]); 
    set(ax(z), 'fontsize', 6);
    set(findobj(ax(z),'Type','text'),'FontSize',  6);

    ylabel('% improvement', 'fontsize',8,'fontweight', 'bold');
    xlabel('Hour of the day', 'fontsize', 8,'fontweight', 'bold');
 end
```

[image]